# How can I calculate the median of all rows?

Tags: sql, oracle

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**
I'd like to calculate the median number of rows for the last 49 days for each store and hour of the day (0 - 24 hours).

**What I've done so far:**
My current SQL is below. I'm using the median function incorrectly and am receiving the following error:  `not a single-group group function`.

```
SELECT 
store,
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(date AS TIMESTAMP)) AS hour_of_day,
median(count(*))

FROM table

WHERE date >= trunc(sysdate - 49) 

GROUP BY 
store,
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(date AS TIMESTAMP))
```

**What I'd like to know:**
Can the median function be used in this manner? If so, is there something I have to change in the *group by* of the query? If not, can you recommend another way to solve this issue?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Oracle, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data and the output you would expect from that sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can do this with window functions.  The relevant analytic functions, such as `median` do not work cumulatively.

But you can use a lateral join:

```
with dh as (
      select trunc(date) as dte, extract(hour from date) as hh,
             shop, count(*) as cnt
      from t
     )
select dh.*, m.median_cnt
from dh cross join lateral
     (select median(cnt) as median_cnt
      from dh dh2
      where dh2.hh = dh.hh and
            dh2.dte >= dh.dte - interval '48' day and
            dh2.dte <= dte
     ) m;
```

Note:  It is not clear what you mean by 49 days.  I assume you want exactly 7 weeks which is 48 days in the past plus the current date on the row.

Also, this ignores `0` values.  If you need to take those into account, then ask a *new* question.